# sudo update-grub doesn't work

Tags: grub2

When I run `sudo update-grub`, I get the below error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: /boot/grub/grub.cfg.: not found
```

I have checked and can confirm that the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file exists and is not empty.

I am fairly new to Linux and appreciate your help.

Please see the below outputs.

`sed -n '2 p' /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig
set -e`

`cat /etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0  
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0  
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true  
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10  
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Whats the output of `sed -n '2 p' /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` and `cat /etc/default/grub`? [edit] your question and add the outputs.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you response! 

I have added the outputs as requested.

Comment: That line looks like you lost the "#" at the beginning, to make the line a comment in the /etc/default/grub file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you've got the correct files on your system.

"update grub" is an Ubuntu specific script, which invokes grub-mkconfig. I can't help you with that...
But you can try without the script. grub-mkconfig will start from /etc/default/grub to make your system boot. While booting grub looks to the grub.cfg file to find other OS'es.

first backup your boot file:

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg  /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup
```

Then run:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And see how that goes...

I'm not working on a ubuntu machine but my grub-mkconfig is located in the /bin folder not sbin like your error output suggests. You can find out by running this code

```
which grub-mkconfig
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm still getting the same output.   

`/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: /boot/grub/grub.cfg.: not found`

Comment: Does this happen when running my suggested code? Even without running "update-grub"?  If the answer is yes, there might be a problem with the configuration file  /etc/default/grub.

Comment: If you did not make any changes to the /etc/default/grub file you can simply replace this by typing :sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub